# When is a coherent sheaf on an algebraizable space algebraizable?

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, rigid-analytic-geometry, gaga

Let $\mathcal{X}$ denote an algebraizable rigid analytic space over $\text{Spm}(\mathbb{Q}_p)$,
i.e. there exists a finite type $\mathbb{Q}_p$-scheme $X$ such that $\mathcal{X}$ is its rigid analytification.
Let $\mathcal{E}$ denote a coherent sheaf on $\mathcal{X}$. Are there any well known conditions beyond $X$ being proper, in which the coherent sheaf $\mathcal{E}$ is algebraizable?

Comment: Beyond trivial variants like "$\mathcal{E}$ has proper support", there is no hope of anything.